# Find the measure of $E=(0,1]\setminus \{\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

### Find the measure of $E=(0,1]\setminus \{\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

---

$E\subseteq [0,1] \Rightarrow m(E)\leq1$

$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})\subseteq E\Rightarrow m(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}))\leq m(E)$

$m(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

let $n\rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow 1\leq m(E)$

$m(E)=1$

Is my solution correct?

Can I prove something stronger with this idea,  maybe that if $A$ is countable then $E\setminus A$ has the same measure as $E$ ?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$ is not $1-\frac1{n+1}$. It's $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a countable set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. Then we can calculate

$m(E) = m(A\cup(E\setminus A))=m(A)+m(E\setminus A)=m(E\setminus A)$.

Comment: ohh much simpler and quick, perfect, thanks

Comment: Just make sure you are allowed to use that countable sets have measure $0$ or prove it yourself. Hint: enumerate the set $q_1,q_2,\dots$ and cover each point with smaller and smaller intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

isn't correct. In fact, on the right side, no $n$ should appear anymore.

What you actually want to say is that for each $N\geq 1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac 1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{N+1}.$$

Then, letting $N\to\infty$, you are left with
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac 1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1.$$

The rest is correct.